# How to solve performing update on immutable fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I am writing a mutation to update a collection in the database

```
updateDiscoverUsers(_id:ID!,input: UpdateDiscoverUsersInput!): DiscoverUsers
```

The resolver function below is the one that handles that mutation

```
updateDiscoverUsers: async (args) => {
    const auth = new DiscoverUsers({
        geohash: args.input.geohash,
        offenses: args.input.offenses,
        online: args.input.online,
        paid: args.input.paid,
        profilePic: args.input.profilePic,
        username: args.input.username,
        creator: "5dab348c8890af1b8c25b22e"
    })

    const value = await DiscoverUsers.findByIdAndUpdate(args._id, { $set: auth }, { useFindAndModify: false, new: true }) 
    if (!value) {
        throw new Error('User doesnt exist')
    }
    return transformUser(value)
}
```

Then below is the type for the value to be returned

```
    type DiscoverUsers{
    _id:ID!
    geohash: String!
    offenses:Int
    online: Int
    paid: Boolean
    profilePic: String
    username: String
    creator: Auth!
}
```

and also below is the input type that holds the value that would be used to update any field in the collection

```
    input UpdateDiscoverUsersInput{
    geohash: String
    offenses:Int
    online: Int
    paid: Boolean
    profilePic: String
    username: String
}
```

But when I try to run the mutation in graphiql as shown below

```
 mutation {
  updateDiscoverUsers(_id:"5dab7c198a83f235c89a964a",input: {geohash:"dudknudnud", username: "Wacha"}){
    username
  }
}
```

I get an error that is displayed in my graphiql

> {
>     "errors": [
>       {
>         "message": "Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'",
>         "locations": [
>           {
>             "line": 2,
>             "column": 3
>           }
>         ],
>         "path": [
>           "updateDiscoverUsers"
>         ]
>       }
>     ],
>     "data": {
>       "updateDiscoverUsers": null
>     }
>   }

I have tried to check where the problem seems to be, have check online and there wasn't a similar problem as this. Any help would be welcome and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please use following code

      const auth = {
      geohash: args.input.geohash,
      offenses: args.input.offenses,
      online: args.input.online,
      paid: args.input.paid,
      profilePic: args.input.profilePic,
      username: args.input.username,
      creator: "5dab348c8890af1b8c25b22e"
    };
    const updateCond={_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(args._id)}
    const value = await DiscoverUsers.findOneAndUpdate(updateCond, auth, { new: true });
```

Comment: Still getting the same problem

Comment: Can you use console.log value after sending me display value

Comment: when I console.log("Update ",update) I get Update  { _id: 5dab3573c4d64e254c44eff1 } but it doesnot log value I guess the query doesn't complete

Comment: please write that line console.log(value); please tell me what is get??

Comment: yes its the right one, of all the CRUD operations the update is still having issues